# How to save a Nested Relation with Entity on API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have two entities, **Question** and **Alternative** where Question has a OneToMany relation with Alternative and I'm trying to send a JSON with a nested document of **Alternative** on it via POST to **Question** API Platform.

The API Platform returns that error below :

```
Nested documents for "alternatives" attribute are not allowed. Use IRIs instead.
```

Searching about it I've found some people saying that is only possible using IRIs and some other people saying that is possible to use Denormalization and Normalization contexts to solve this problem but I can't find some example or tutorial about it.

**TL;DR;**

Is there a way to send a nested relation into an entity POST on API Platform without using IRIs?

**UPDATE:**

As asked, please see below the two mappings of Question and Alternative entities.

**Question**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Question implements CreatedAtEntityInterface, UpdatedAtEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Token", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="question_versions")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $question_versions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max="100")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     */
    private $enunciation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     */
    private $material;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $public;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Alternative", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $alternatives;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionProperty", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $properties;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionAbility", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $abilities;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionCompetency", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $competencies;
}
```

**Alternative**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AlternativeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="alternatives")
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Alternative implements CreatedAtEntityInterface, UpdatedAtEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="alternatives")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     */
    private $enunciation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AlternativeProperty", mappedBy="alternatives")
     */
    private $properties;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the api-platform mappings of the two entities. For a *serialization context*  example see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically

Comment: @fyrye I've updated the question as you asked – Bruno de Souza Rocha just now    Edit

Comment: You are not using any serializer groups or any other contexts?

Comment: No, I'm using only the api resource alone

Comment: This SymfonyCast  Video showed me Exactly how to solve this problem using `denormalizationContext` annotation! https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/collections-create

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try implement [Denormalization](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization)

Question:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"post"}}
 * )
 */
class Question implements CreatedAtEntityInterface, UpdatedAtEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Token", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="question_versions")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", mappedBy="question")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $question_versions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max="100")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $enunciation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $material;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $public;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Alternative", mappedBy="question")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $alternatives;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionProperty", mappedBy="question")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $properties;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionAbility", mappedBy="question")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $abilities;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionCompetency", mappedBy="question")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $competencies;
}
```

Alternative:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AlternativeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="alternatives")
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Alternative implements CreatedAtEntityInterface, UpdatedAtEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="alternatives")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="65535")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $enunciation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AlternativeProperty", mappedBy="alternatives")
     * @Groups({"post"})
     */
    private $properties;
}
```

Now you can this send JSON to POST/PUT without IRI:

```
{
    "token": "/api/tokens/1",
    "question": "string",
    "version": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "type": 0,
    "enunciation": "string",
    "public": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "alternatives": [
        {
            "enunciation": "String",
            "createdAt": "2018-01-01 11:11:11",
            "updatedAt": "2018-01-01 11:11:11"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it was exactly that! You saved my afternoon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice one ! this solution work me too, thank you

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who has a problem with the error cascade persist you have to add it in the OneToMany property.That is, for our question:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Alternative", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})
```

Comment: For those who have still problems with persisting the related entity (namely foreign keys not getting set on the “many” side), make sure to set the mapped property in the target entity to `$this` in the add method and `null` in the remove method as being done and noted in [the example here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started/#mapping-the-entities). Took me many hours of research and trial’n’error before finding this piece of critical information in a corner of the docs where I wouldn’t have expected it.

Comment: @dulange your excellent answer should have more votes :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and `denormalizationContext` didn't fix my problem.
So, I removed `@ApiResource()` from `Alternative` class.

I already had

`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Alternative", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})`

If you don't want to expose the `Alternative` Entity, then removing it will work with no problem