# API Platform and/or Doctrine tries to update ALL existing entities when updating an entity with embedded relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a OneToMany relation of a Checklist and it's Answers set up so consumers can update a Checklist and add Answers to it.

This works fine when there are no answers in the answers table, but when there are something goes wrong and API Platform and/or Doctrine wants to update ALL of the answers, leading to the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE answer SET checklist_id = ?, updated = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, \"2019-08-18 12:44:55\", 96]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'checklist_id' cannot be null
```

I receive this error when PUT-ing the following request body to `/api/checklists/2`

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "answer": "Ok",
            "user": "/api/users/9",
            "question": "/api/questions/3"
        },
        {
            "answer": "NotK",
            "user": "/api/users/9",
            "question": "/api/questions/4"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the configuration of both entities:

Answer:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\DefaultTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

/**
 * Class Answer
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *         "normalization_context"={"groups"={"answer:read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *         "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"answer:write", "checklist:write"}}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="answer")
 */
class Answer
{
    use DefaultTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"answer:read", "answer:write", "checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * @Groups({"answer:read", "answer:write", "checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Checklist", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"answer:read", "answer:write", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $checklist;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"answer:read", "answer:write", "checklist:write"})
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $question;

    # Getters and setters omitted
}
```

Checklist:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use AppBundle\Annotation\CompanyAware;
use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\EnabledTrait;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\DefaultTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "force_eager"=false,
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"checklist:read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"checklist:write"}, "enable_max_depth"=true}
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="checklist")
 * @CompanyAware(companyFieldName="company_id")
 */
class Checklist
{
    use DefaultTrait;
    use EnabledTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Checklist")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="checklist")
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\QuestionGroup", mappedBy="checklist", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $groups;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Question", mappedBy="checklist", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $questions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="checklists")
     * @Groups({"checklist:read", "checklist:write"})
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="checklist", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"checklist:write"})
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $answers;
}
```

Comment: The error message you get seems to be quite clear: `Column 'checklist_id' cannot be null`. Either assign a value other then null or change the column definition.

Comment: @digijay That would be the workaround, but that seems redundant as i'm updating the checklist and supplying the id in the request URL. Moreover, this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478759/how-to-save-a-nested-relation-with-entity-on-api-platform) specifically asks how to do so without and has a solution so I feel like adding the checklist id to every answer is unnecessary.

Comment: I think the ultimate problem is this: the answers are persisted in database and added answers will appear as completely new, so the old answers will be unlinked (`checklist_id` set to null, which is forbidden according to schema - which imho indicates you need `orphanRemoval`), and the new answers will be added as new entities. your setter probably just looks like `function setAnswers($answers) { $this->answers = $answers; }` which in my experience so far works extremely badly with collections, since the old collection is lost and the changeset will completely unlink the old collection ...

Comment: @Jakumi, orphanRemoval seems a step in the right direction. I no longer get an error, but the answers don't remain in the database. I do see them in the api response so it seems like they make it to the database but are then removed almost immediately... Their id also keeps increasing.

Comment: have you checked the profiler for the queries that are run? maybe the transactions are rolled back... on the other hand, maybe the checklist ids don't get set on the answers. sadly I'm not really familiar with api-platform so ... there might be something non-obvious.